# Where is the HTML file relating to the line of options below the search bar?

Tags: magento2.3, header

I am trying to add/remove a few links from this line in the header. However, the code is not a block, and so is not available through the backend. Each part is its own block, and though I found the search bar, I have not found the part relating to the links. And help at all would be great.

---

[image: Image of the line of text referenced]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above links are in top.links block. You can remove it through the below code.

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           
    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      
    <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          
    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="register-link">
        <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Constact Us</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-us</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Thanks

Comment: While this helps, it does not help in adding new items to the block. Could you please explain further on that point?

Comment: Please check updated answer